# Fit div into screen using optimal scale ratio

Tags: javascript, html

I've a game with a determined frame size:

```
// The level frame original size
const frameWidth = 1140;
const frameHeight = 518;
```

I've tried different libraries for 2D rendering and I gave up of them either for bug or lack of features and anyway my game is cloud-based, so all the client does is mostly receive world packets, send packets and render the world. I'm betting the browser's native HTML rendering won't be a problem.

I want to fit this frame into the window; it must take its most minimal scale ratio that fits into the screen and get centered there:

```
import ScreenSize from '@/app/util/ScreenSize';

export default function optimalFitRatio(originalSize: ScreenSize, fitToSize: ScreenSize): number {
    const horizontalRatio = fitToSize.width / originalSize.width;
    const verticalRatio = fitToSize.height / originalSize.height;
    return Math.min(horizontalRatio, verticalRatio);
}
```

Now, the problem is that I see that the position of the world entities vary depending on the window resolution. I wasn't having this problem when using the mentioned "libraries".

Minimal reproduction:

```js
function optimalFitRatio(originalSize, fitToSize) {
    const horizontalRatio = fitToSize.width / originalSize.width;
    const verticalRatio = fitToSize.height / originalSize.height;
    return Math.min(horizontalRatio, verticalRatio);
}

// The level frame original size
const frameWidth = 1140;
const frameHeight = 518;

class LevelView {
    container1 = undefined;
    container2 = undefined;
    resizeListener = undefined;
    attached = false;

    scale = 0;
    width = 0;
    height = 0;

    attach() {
        this.attached = true;

        // Create first container
        this.newContainer();

        // Resizing
        this.resizeListener = this.resizeFrame.bind(this);
        window.addEventListener('resize', this.resizeListener);
        this.resizeFrame();
    }

    detach() {
        window.removeEventListener('resize', this.resizeListener);
        this.container1?.remove();

        this.attached = false;
    }

    renderLevel(world) {
        this.container1?.remove();
        this.newContainer();
        this.orientContainer();

        // Sort Z index
        // sortEntitiesByZ(world.entities);

        for (const entity of world.entities) {
            if (entity.type == "Entity") {
                this.renderEntity(entity);
            }
        }
    }

    renderEntity(entity) {
        // Orient the bitmap
        const orient = shape => {
            shape.style.position = "fixed";
            shape.style.left = `${entity.x}px`;
            shape.style.top = `${entity.y}px`;
            shape.style.transform = `rotate(${entity.rotationRadians}rad)`;
            shape.style.transformOrigin = "center";
            shape.style.userSelect = "none";
        };

        // Create the bitmap
        const bitmap = document.createElement("img");
        bitmap.src = "https://i.imgur.com/Dx200x9.png";
        orient(bitmap);
        this.container2.appendChild(bitmap);
    }

    resizeFrame() {
        if (!this.attached) {
            return;
        }

        // Fit the level frame original size into the actual resolution
        const ratio = optimalFitRatio(
            { width: frameWidth, height: frameHeight },
            { width: window.innerWidth, height: window.innerHeight },
        );

        // Cache properties
        this.width = frameWidth * ratio;
        this.height = frameHeight * ratio;
        this.scale = ratio;

        // Orient
        this.orientContainer();
    }

    orientContainer() {
        // Resize the container
        const [w, h] = [this.width, this.height];
        this.container1.style.width = `${w}px`;
        this.container1.style.height = `${h}px`;

        // Scale the second container
        this.container2.style.transform = `scale(${this.scale})`;

        // Translate the container
        this.container1.style.left = `${window.innerWidth / 2 - w / 2}px`;
        this.container1.style.top = `${window.innerHeight / 2 - h / 2}px`;
    }

    newContainer() {
        const c0 = document.body;

        const c1 = document.createElement('div');
        c1.style.display = "inline-block";
        c1.style.background = "#000";
        c1.style.overflow = "hidden";
        c1.style.position = "fixed";
        c1.style.userSelect = "none";
        c0.appendChild(c1);
        this.container1 = c1;

        const c2 = document.createElement('div');
        c1.appendChild(c2);
        this.container2 = c2;
    }
}

const levelView = new LevelView();
levelView.attach();
levelView.renderLevel({
    entities: [{
        type: "Entity",
        x: 100,
        y: 100,
        rotationRadians: 0,
    }],
});
```

(Updated: I forgot `{ type: "Entity", ...p }` above. Now you should see the issue...)

Answer (score 1):

For perfect aspect ratio, add a `<canvas>` element and place your actual canvas on top of it.
As for keeping the sizes of elements inside - use percentages.
Something like this:

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100dvh;
}

.game {
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  min-height: 0;
}

.game canvas {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}

.game-canvas {
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;
  background: black;
}

.game-canvas img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 10%;
  bottom: 10%;
  width: 20%;
}
```

```html
<div class="game">
  <canvas width="1140" height="518"></canvas>
  <div class="game-canvas">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/Dx200x9.png">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there a way to let it scale more than the original also?